# Rails 3 unit tests not running under RVM/Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am having a bit of a head scratching moment here.  I have a fairly new rails project that I can not get the unit tests to run.

```
[~/source/quibbler]
13:47:50 aburns@horcrux$ rvm -v

rvm 1.7.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]


[~/source/quibbler]
13:47:56 aburns@horcrux$ cat .rvmrc 
rvm use 1.9.2@quibbler --create


[~/source/quibbler]
13:49:07 aburns@horcrux$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p290@quibbler


[~/source/quibbler]
13:47:59 aburns@horcrux$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.10


[~/source/quibbler]
13:49:35 aburns@horcrux$ ls test/unit/
content_test.rb helpers     user_test.rb


[~/source/quibbler]
13:48:03 aburns@horcrux$ rake test:units
Loaded suite /Users/aburns/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started

Finished in 0.002316 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 37195
```

My gut says this has something to do with RVM because of the gemset mismatch on the suite line and the project gemset.  I am not even sure on where to start on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've updated to Rails 3.1 or not ?

Comment: Does it work on 1.8.7? When I moved from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 I started having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using authlogic in your applications? I found this broke my tests in exactly the same way as yours when using the `subclass.instance_eval` line. If you are, just use `setup :activate_authlogic` at the class level rather than inside the `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell bundler which rake to use:
`bundle exec rake test:units`